# Wait for Camera.PictureCallback

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

Scenario:

I have a Activity (A) that calls another Activity (B) to take a picture and send the `Byte[]` back to 'A'.

Activity B has a Button in order to take the picture:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //get the current image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            Intent data1 = new Intent();
            data1.putExtra("byte_array",dataPic);
            if (getParent() == null) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data1);
            } else {
                getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data1);
            }
            finish();

        }
```

and this is my PictureCallback:

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " +
                    "no exception written by a boss");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            dataPic = data;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();

    }
};
```

I started Activity B with `startActivityForResult` and implemented `onActivityResult` in Activity A.

Problem:

I debugged through my code and noticed that `onActivityResult` gets called before `onPictureTaken` does. So logically the `Byte[]` is null :(

I also tried to add the code inside the `onClick` function to the `onPictureTaken` function (of course without the `mCamera.takePicture`),
with no avail, still null.

Maybe I'm not seeing something really obvious, but I just can't find the solution. I tried looking for a fitting question here, but couldn't find anything that helped.

Question:

Is there a way to wait for the callback? or maybe another approach of solving the problem?

Side note:

Please no suggestions to use Camera Intent.

Comment: Maybe put `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data1);` inside `onPictureTaken`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I debugged through my code and noticed that onActivityResult gets called before onPictureTaken does. So logically the Byte[] is null

That is because `takePicture()` is asynchronous.

> I also tried to add the code inside the onClick function to the onPictureTaken function (of course without the mCamera.takePicture), with no avail, still null.

Well, with respect to dealing with the asynchronous issue, this one is the correct answer. However, unless you chose a small resolution, your `Intent` will be too big, and you should crash when trying to send back the result.

> Is there a way to wait for the callback?

No.

> or maybe another approach of solving the problem?

With respect to the "`Intent` too large" issue, don't have two activities. Have one activity, using two fragments or some similar approach towards changing your UI between the two states.

With respect to the asynchronous issue, move your process-the-results logic to `onPictureTaken()`, after `mCamera.release()`. Along the way, get rid of `dataPic` (as you no longer need it) and work with `data` (the passed-in `byte[]`).

Comment: wow how come didn't I think of the simplest solution, moving the process-the-results. thank you!